# How to use pathfinder to cut a rounded rectangle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to create an Illustrator object that is half of a rounded rectangle, such that the top two corners are rounded and the bottom two are not. I thought I could simply start with my rounded rectangle, place a rectangle on top of it, and use "Minus Front" in the pathfinder. However, this causes the resulting shape to have four round corners, not two as I was expecting.

To illustrate:

[image]

After "Minus Front":

[image]

(note how round corners appear along the "cut" line! aargh!)

I suspect I'm missing some key concept here. How can I prevent the rounded corners from spreading like this?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a rounded rectangle but rather a square rectangle with very thick borders set with a rounded corners. To get what you want, draw a rounded rectangle sans borders, then use the pathfinder on that.

Comment: That's the right answer. Better as an answer than a comment, eh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though you are using the 'rounded rectangle' effect in the effects pallet oppose to actually making a rounded rectangle, so when its changing your rectangle its changing your path but still applying the rounded rectangle effect which is whats making all of the corners round off.

Try using the Rounded rectangle tool oppose to the rectangle tool and you can manipulate the radius of the corners by pressing the up and down arrow keys whilst making your rounded edge box.

The pathfinder should work if you do that.

Comment: ah, so obvious in retrospect! thanks also to DA01 for the commented answer.

Answer (score 3):

First hit expand appearance, the rounded effect is then turned into a 'normal' path. 
Pathfinder should now work (menu -> object -> expand appearance).

Answer (score 0):

Select your object and choose "Object -> Expand Appearance".

This will allow you to edit your object if you've used the effect "Round Rectangle" OR the Rectangle Tool.